# RegEx - Match either of two conditions

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
@Function1['param1', -100, 'param3'] * 120 + @Function2 - 15.5
```

Here `@Function1` and `@Function2` are name of functions and may be any word ([a-z]+). Function name will always begin with `@`.

How do we write a RegEx expression so that I get both the functions:

```
@Function1['param1', -100, 'param3']
@Function2
```

If a function name is followed by `[` then I need everything up to the next `]`, otherwise just the function name.

I have tried the following regex, but it works for upto only 1 parameter. It stops at the first comma after the function name which has parameters.

```
@[^\s\]]+?[\s\]]
```

**Edit:**

I think this does the job, but not sure I'll miss any cases?

```
@\w+?(?:\[.+?\])?(?:\s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I should answer my own question. *(Sorry for posting the question without trying too hard)*

This is the best I could get to:

```
@\w+?(?:\[[^]]+?\])?(?=\s)
```

It matches the function name, then anything between `[` and `]` is made optional. And the search ends with the next space.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
\@\w*(\s|\[.*])
```

With the global flag set

Comment: The `\s` should be optional, otherwise `@Function2` won't be matched.

Comment: It'll fail if `@Function2` is not followed by anything.

Comment: This misbehaves if there are two functions with [x]. It selects all in between those two functions also.